# Are stationary points preserved when squaring a function under an integral?

Tags: integration, optimization, definite-integrals, stationary-point

Say
$T(b)=\int_0^{10}f(b,x)dx$. I want to find the value of $b$ which minimises $T$ but evaluating that integral is quite difficult. If $f(b,x)$ was squared, however, it would be easier. So my question is are the stationary points for $\int_0^{10}f(b,x)dx$ the same as for $\int_0^{10}[f(b,x)]^2dx$? $f$ will be something of the form of $\sqrt{\frac{1+[-\frac{b+1}{5}x+b]^2}{-\frac{b+1}{10}x^2+bx}}$.

Comment: do you have any assumptions on $f$ ?

Comment: No such rule will generally hold.  But under certain conditions, like separability ($ f(b,x) = g(b)h(x) $), you could get away with this.

Comment: Ok, I added what $f$ will be like for more clarity, though I don't think it's separable.